# Custom fields in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I've looked at Sonar for a way to include custom fields for grouping/filtering data on-the-fly, including at [addon extension points](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+plugin), but haven't seen anything that meets my criteria.

For example, for a multi-team project where all teams share the same repository project, I'd like to be able to filter the standard reports for single teams (encoding the team data for instance in a custom java annotation).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this discussion on the mailinglist: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/10059 ... http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/10073

It is not possibile to have group-specific dashboards/reports/views. The only thing supported right now are filters.

I'm not aware of any custom solution.

Comment: Thanks. I guess a workaround with a custom metric and filter would do the job.